# How to join functionality of @ContextConfiguration and @SpringBootTest (Java SpringBoot)?

Tags: java, spring

i have the test class, with @ContextConfiguration, which works:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "my.xml", initializers = MyTest.MockJee.class)
public class MyTest {
...
}
```

I have the abstract test class, with @SpringBootTest, his childs works too:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnviroment = SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = App.class)
public abstract class MyAbstractTest {
...
}
```

When i try, to give MyAbstractTest @ContextConfiguration (I want to extends from MyAbstractTest class for MyTest),the initializer from @ContextConfiguration work, but results of them doesn't save in context, and the result is crush.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnviroment = SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = App.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "my.xml", initializers = MyTest.MockJee.class)
public abstract class MyAbstractTest {
...
}
```

So how to join functionality of @ContextConfiguration and @SpringBootTest?